# User basically takes your answer, posts it as his own and accepts his?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Granted most of the questions asked here are way over my head but in the rare occasion where I see a question I can assist with, Im more than happy to offer my time.

I just looked up one of my old answers and saw that the user basically took my answer, changed the directory a little, submitted it and chose it as the accepted answer?   Does this happen often?

I guess this kinda irked me..

Comment: If you want an answer from the OP, why he didn't accept your answer, you should comment his question, not your answer.

Comment: its behind me, besides, what good would it do?

Comment: I don't know, DataPimp. You asked the question ;)

Comment: I've even seen someone copy the correct answer into someone else's wrong answer, and then accept that for a bounty... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767236/reading-custom-httpwebresponse-statusdescription/801141#801141 Odd ;-)

Answer (score 15):

I don't think that guy was being malicious (after all he doesn't get any rep for accepting his own answer).

Basically I think the issue just came down to the fact that the folder you pointed to didn't exist on his machine, and he wasn't familiar enough with windows to know that `C:/Documents and Settings/` is the Windows XP structure and that he should replace it with `C:/Users` for his Windows 7 install.

Comment: But, the user was still correct, because DataPimp's answer didn't answer the question.

Comment: (Just for the archives, as the OP removed the link to the question: the copied answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458086/user-instance-failure-error-when-creating-a-service-based-database-in-vs-2008-and/1458137#1458137, originally posted as "DataPimp", now owned by "Leroy Jenkins".)

Answer (score 12):

I've had this happen. It sucks... The user had a chance to reward you for your help, and didn't. Some people are like that. Just brush it off and move on.

Answer (score 7):

If it was a pure copy, I would be mad, but I think there is a bit of difference to show that he did try your version and it didn't help him. - And as TM said, he probably did not realise / understand.

I had a similar issue on Superuser.com where I posted a link showing you need to use %userprofile%\something (I forget now), and then the owner, about 20 minutes later wrote the full thing "C:\users\name\something" and accepted, where as if he actually tried my thing, it should have worked on any version of Windows.

He even wrote, I went to My computer and could not find the %userprofile% directory... oh well!

Also, you don't know, he may have given you an upvote in that thread :S

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue in this particular thread is just that the asker didn't even realize that the other guy answered his question correctly.  It's easy to assume a certain level of knowledge that isn't always there.

Comment: @TM +1 I agree... I haven't looked in to this person, but unless he had done it several times, like in my example, I do not think it is malicious.

Comment: Oh I agree not malicious, but seriously... how close does it have to be.. once he found the directory and deleted it, you would think.. hmmm, that sure sounds familiar.  :)

Shog9 is right, its past me now.